# Creating a range slider for datetime

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a range slider using HTML/CSS/Javascript.

I want the range to be between two dates, but in doing so I want not only the date to be displayed, but also the corresponding time: so for example 2022-10-01-12:00:00.

I looked up the code for a range slider and found the following, but this only shows the date with the day of the week, which should not appear in my display.
I just don't know how to modify this code to achieve the required result.

```
 $(function () {
            $("#slider-range").slider({
                range: true,
                min: new Date('2010.01.01').getTime() / 1000,
                max: new Date('2014.01.01').getTime() / 1000,
                step: 86400,
                values: [new Date('2013.01.01').getTime() / 1000, new Date('2013.02.01').getTime() / 1000],
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#amount").val((new Date(ui.values[0] * 1000).toDateString()) + " - " + (new Date(ui.values[1] * 1000)).toDateString());
                }
            });
            $("#amount").val((new Date($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) * 1000).toDateString()) +
                " - " + (new Date($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) * 1000)).toDateString());
        });
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>
    <label for="amount">Date range:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" size="100" />
</p>
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  function toSec(dateString) {
    // Extract a date from a string value with a specified format.
    // See: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/
    var dt = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy.mm.dd", dateString);
    return dt.getTime() / 1000;
  }

  function secToDate(s) {
    var dt = new Date(s * 1000);
    // Format a date into a string value with a specified format.
    // See: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/
    return $.datepicker.formatDate("yy.mm.dd", dt);
  }

  $("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: toSec('2010.01.01'),
    max: toSec('2014.01.01'),
    step: 86400,
    values: [toSec('2013.01.01'), toSec('2013.02.01')],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#amount").val(secToDate(ui.values[0]) + " - " + secToDate(ui.values[1]));
    }
  });

  $("#amount").val(secToDate($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0)) +
    " - " + secToDate($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1)));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="amount">Date range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" size="100" />
</p>
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

As you are using jQuery UI, you can make use of some of the utilities functions for DatePicker: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

> `$.datepicker.formatDate( format, date )`
> `$.datepicker.parseDate( format, value )`

I added functions that make it easier to convert a Date String, like 2010.01.01 into a Date Object and return the Seconds and vice versa to convert the number of Seconds back to a Date String.